# Photoshopping a logo onto a curved 3D object like a can

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-7

I have a logo that I want to place on a graphic. On certain graphics, the logo is bigger than the "flat" surface, so I want to "bend" the logo appropriately to make it look real.

For example, on the image below:

[image: can of 7-UP]

the 7-UP logo bends around the can. When I put a logo on a curved surface, it looks wrong. What is the technique for making the logo match the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adding a Label to a bottle myjanee.com Photoshop Tutorial](http://www.myjanee.com/tuts/3dtransform/3dtransform.htm)

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to use Photoshop CS4 Extended, which can create a 3D effect by wrapping a 2D image around a 3D geometrical object. 
**The following information was taken from [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/photoshop/articles/lrvid4006_ps.html):**

---

> To wrap a 2D object around a 3D object:
>
> Prerequisite knowledge Basic knowledge of how to import images, create
>   layers, use the Photoshop toolbox, and navigate the Layers panel.
>
> CONVERTING FROM 2D TO 3D
>
> Adobe® Photoshop® CS4 Extended has several new features that allow you
>   to create three-dimensional content. In this tutorial, you will learn
>   how to wrap a 2D image around a 3D geometrical object, transform a 2D
>   object into a 3D plane, and create volume renderings of DICOM (Digital
>   Imaging and Communications in Medicine) sequences and pixel layers.
>   You will also learn how to use gray values to create a depth map,
>   composite 2D and 3D data, and create 3D spherical panoramas.
>
> WRAPPING A 2D IMAGE AROUND A 3D GEOMETRICAL OBJECT
>
> Photoshop CS4 Extended can create a 3D effect by wrapping a 2D image
>   around a 3D geometrical object. To wrap a 2D object around a 3D
>   object:
>
> Open the sample file named archer_DC-2706.tif in Photoshop. Select the
>   layer with the photographic image and choose 3D > New Shape From Layer
>
> > Cylinder. A cylinder appears with the 3D image wrapped around it. The 3D Axis widget also appears, allowing you to move, scale, and
> >     rotate the image along the x, y, and z axes.
>
> Figure 1: Wrapping a 2D image around a 3D geometrical object Note: Now
>   that you have created a 3D object, you can add lights and cameras,
>   change its materials, and paint on it. Basically, you can do anything
>   to the 3D object that you can do to any other 3D layer. TRANSFORMING A
>   2D IMAGE INTO A 3D PLANE
>
> Photoshop CS4 Extended also has a new feature that allows you to take
>   advantage of 3D features using simple 2D layers. You can now add a
>   spotlight to an image or rotate an image in 3D space by transforming a
>   2D image into a 3D plane: To transform a 2D image:
>
> Use the sample file named arcer_DC-2706.tif to complete this exercise.
>   Choose 3D > New 3D Postcard From Layer. You have created a 3D object
>   from a 2D photographic image. Note that the image still appears flat.
>
> Figure 2: Creating a 3D object out of a 2D image Choose the 3D
>   Rotation tool from the toolbox. You can move the image using the 3D
>   Axis widget to demonstrate that it is indeed a 3D plane. This plane
>   respects 3D cameras and lights you create in Photoshop.
>
> Figure 3: Using the 3D Rotation tool VOLUME RENDERING WITH DICOM
>   LAYERS
>
> Photoshop CS4 Extended allows you to create a volume rendering of
>   Digital Imaging and Communications Medicine (DICOM) images. A DICOM
>   sequence is a series of cross-section stills. To open a DICOM
>   sequence:
>
> Choose File > Open and open the sample file named legs_stacked.dcm.
>   Use the Up Arrow and Down Arrow keys to navigate through the sequence
>   of DICOM images. To create a volume rendering, click Select All at the
>   top of the DICOM sequence and select all images in the sequence.
>
> [image: Figure 4]: Selecting images from a DICOM sequence Under Frame
>   Import Options, select Import As Volume. Click Open. When Photoshop
>   imports the DICOM sequence as a volume, it creates the illusion that
>   all those images have created a 3D volume.
>
> [image: Figure 5]: Creating a volume rendering of a DICOM sequence Note:
>   When you import a DICOM sequence, the 3D panel displays a series of
>   DICOM-specific render modes.
>
> [image: Figure 6:] The 3D panel You can also create a volume rendering
>   with your own pixel layers. To do this, choose 3D > New Volume From
>   Layers. USING GRAY VALUES TO GENERATE A DEPTH MAP
>
> Photoshop CS4 also allows you to use gray values to generate a depth
>   map. To create a depth map:
>
> Open Gradient Map.psd. Choose 3D > New Mesh From Grayscale > Plane.
>   Note:Although you are starting with an RGB image, Photoshop looks at
>   the luminance values to determine which elements should be raised, and
>   which should be sunken. Photoshop raises the light areas and sinks the
>   dark areas to create an illusion of depth. To adjust the amount of
>   extrusion, choose the 3D Axis widget. Select the square control
>   located near the tip of the green arrow representing the y axis. When
>   you select the square control, it turns yellow.
>
> [image: Figure 7]: The 3D Axis widget Drag the square control up to
>   decrease the amount of extrusion. Drag the square control down to
>   increase the amount of extrusion. Note: The image is a complete 3D
>   object that respects lights, cameras, materials, etc. COMPOSITING 2D
>   AND 3D DATA
>
> In Photoshop CS4 Extended, you can composite 2D and 3D data.
>
> Return to Gradient Map.psd. Create a new blank pixel layer by clicking
>   the new layer icon at the bottom of the Layers panel.
>
> [image: Figure 8]: The Layers panel Choose a fill color using the
>   Foreground Color icon in the Photoshop toolbox. Press
>   Alt+Backspace/Option+Delete to fill the blank pixel layer with the
>   foreground color. Select the new pixel layer and then choose Merge
>   Down from the pop-up menu in the Layers panel. The original layer is
>   still a 3D object, with the red data from the new pixel layer merged
>   at the top of the surface.
>
> [image: Figure 9]: A composite 3D object with red tint CREATING 3D
>   SPHERICAL PANORAMAS
>
> An additional feature of Photoshop CS4 Extended is the ability to
>   create 3D spherical panoramas. To wrap a panorama around a 3D sphere:
>
> Open the sample file named courtyard1.psd.
>
> [image: Figure 10]: A panorama image Choose 3D > New Shape From Layer >
>   Spherical Panorama. Zoom out of and rotate the image to view a 360
>   degree panorama. To fix the north- and south-pole distortions, use the
>   Merge Down techniques described in the previous section of this
>   tutorial.
>
> [image: Figure 11]: A 360º degree panoramic view

I got a bit tired of inserting the pictures in manually, just visit the [Adobe Photoshop Tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/photoshop/articles/lrvid4006_ps.html)

Comment: The image of the can - while in the real-world is a 3D object, it is only a 2D image and will not be treated as a 3D object in Photoshop.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I did both, not everyone wants to open a new tab or go to another web page.

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin It's generally [recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to have more than just a link.